# How to append dictionary with objects to an array using FIrebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with firebase i'm able to get as response a dictionary that look's like this:

```
▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "maskForHair"
    ▿ value : 3 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : id
        - value : 1
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : name
        - value : Hair Mask
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : note
        - value : asd
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "hairShampo"
    ▿ value : 3 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : id
        - value : 0
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : name
        - value : hairShampo
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : note
        - value : asd
```

now i'm trying to populate a tableView using this dictionary, But i cant find a way to append this dict to an array, Any ideas?

This is how my getCategories function looks like:

```
func getCategories(){

    dbHandle = dbRefernce?.child("categories").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any]{

            print(dictionary)

            let category = Categories(dictionary: dictionary)
            self.categoriesArr.append(category)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.categoriesTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And here how my Categories class looks like:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Categories: NSObject {

    var name : String? = nil
    var id : Int? = nil
    var note : String? = nil

    init (dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        super.init()
        name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
        note = dictionary["note"] as? String
    }

}
```

Comment: can you print     this   print(dictionary)

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish hi there, i already did its in the 1st block of code

Comment: There are a few issues. 1) loose the *DispatchQueue.main.async* as firebase closures run on the main thread anyway  2) You are readingin the entire categories node, which includes ALL of the child nodes. That is not going to match up with your Categories class as it's expecting just ONE node. 3) To fix, you should iterate over the child nodes returned in the snapshot and create a category for each child, not all at once.

Comment: oh and to take #3 a step further, each child (maskForHair, hairShampo etc) has a number of child nodes. So again, that doesn't match your Category class as it's expecting each of those child nodes separately, so they would need to be iterated over as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i worked it out:

```
 for index in 1...self.numberOfProducts{

        dbHandle = dbRefernce?.child("categories").child("\(index)").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let name = value["name"] as? String,
                let imageURL = value["imageURL"] as? String,
                let desc = value["description"] as? String,
                let price  = value["price"] as? Int,
                let id = value["subCategoryID"] as? Int
                else {return}


            let category = Product(name: name, imageURL: imageURL, description: desc, price: price,subCategoryID: id)

            self.productsArr.append(category)
            self.tblProducts.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

Just created an object and then append it to the array,
you can do this in a loop

Answer (score 0):

I would start by renaming you model into something singular like `HairCategory`.

You need to iterate the children of the snapshot that you receive from the database. Each child should be a `[String : Any]` dictionary that could then be turned into a `HairCategory`.

Something like this:

```
let children = snapshot.children.compactMap { $0 as? DataSnapshot }
let cateroryDictionaries = children.compactMap { $0.value as? [String:Any] }
let categories = cateroryDictionaries.map { dict -> HairCategory in
    return HairCategory.init(dictionary: dict)
}
```

Then `categories` is of type: `[HairCategory]`. If also you make your `self.categoriesArr` of type `[HairCategory]` you can append the newly fetched categories :)

**Edit**:

I can also recommend taking a look at this library: [CodableFirebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase)
. It makes conversion from DataSnapshot to you Models and the other way, really easy..

**Edit**

Just to clarify... You can't "append dictionary ... to an array", you need to convert the dictionary to an array, and then you can append that array to another array of the same type :)

Comment: hi and thank you for you'r answer, i'm trying to make a menu of categories so i can't make a class for each category because i'm trying to make the code know how to work alone with new categories added from the server side without touching the code itself. ill take a look on that library and will update.

Comment: But as long as each category has `name`, `id` and `note`, you should be able to use the same model for them. Otherwise you can use a protocol to let multiple model-types implement the same functions, such at `init(dictionary:)`. I'm don't think that library will solve your problem alone, but It could add some nice sugar on top..

Comment: Why can't you append a dictionary to an array? An array can hold a variety of objects such as strings, ints, objects, dictionaries, structures etc. The OP's dictionary contains ALL child notes so that's not right but you can certainly append a Dictionary to an Array.